# Example Facebook object code.

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

This is the sample code i get from Facebook for the using custom objects. I created this with a custom action to make use of the Facebook story. 
Facebook Documentation:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/overview/

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
[FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"sotd_facebook:new_zombie"
                                        title:@"Sample New Zombie"
                                        image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                          url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/191078581053171"
                                  description:@""];;

[FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/sotd_facebook:new_zombie"
                               graphObject:object
                         completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                             id result,
                                             NSError *error) {
                             // handle the result
                         }];
```

Im curious how can i use this object for an action in the Facebook IOS sdk.
I have tried to use the following codes and it crash upon creating the FBRequestConnection.

```
[__NSCFBoolean dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3af00530
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFBoolean dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3af00530'
```

[edit]
I have created FBOpenGraphObject and use FBRequestConnection method startForPostOpenGraphObject: completionHandler.
Within the completion handler, i retrieve the id from the result and put it in another FBOpenGraphObject with the id.
and it still crash.

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [FBGraphObject
                                                  openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"sotd_facebook:new_zombie"
                                                  title:@"Sample New Zombie"
                                                  image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                                  url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/191078581053171"
                                                  description:@""];



[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object
                               completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                   id result,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                                   // handle the result
                                   // handle the result
                                   if (error)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Error sharing story: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                   }
                                   else if(result != nil)
                                   {
                                       NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                       NSString* resultID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];

                                       NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *newObject = [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPost];
                                       newObject.id = resultID;


                                       [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/sotd_facebook:new_zombie"
                                                                          graphObject:newObject                                                                        completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                                                        id result,
                                                                                        NSError *error) {
                                                                        // handle the result
                                                                        // handle the result
                                                                        if (error)
                                                                        {
                                                                            NSLog(@"Error sharing story: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                                                                        }
                                                                        else
                                                                        {
                                                                            NSLog(@"Result: %@", result);
                                                                        }

                                                                    }];
                                   }

                               }];
```

The crash log:

> 2013-08-16 18:47:11.013 ZombieBlackout[3408:907] -[__NSCFBoolean
>   dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3a118530
>   2013-08-16 18:47:11.015 ZombieBlackout[3408:907] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFBoolean dataUsingEncoding:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x3a118530'

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue. You first need to post the object, then get its ID, and provide the object ID instead of the object itself:

```
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object = [...];
[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                if(result != nil){
                    NSString* resultID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/sotd_facebook:new_zombie"
                               graphObject:resultID //...
```

The object is first posted as an object to Facebook, then you can use the action (new_zombie) on the object. I'm also in the exact same situation (with July 2013 breaking changes enabled) trying to figure out to create all in one step on Facebook, but couldn't figure it out without using a seperate, self-hosted webserver. In my issue, I'm getting an error about the object being already posted and can't be posted again. If you don't have this issue, you can go on with this one now.

It seems that the error itself is caused by the `fbsdk:create_object` key (and its value `1`) in the object dictionary. This key is automatically added by Facebook SDK into the object. When I removed this key explicitly before posting, it did not throw an exception on post, but my answer about posting the object still applies. Even if you remove that key, you'll be getting an `OAuthException` at the server side, telling that the object is not a "reference". I'd be really glad to be proven wrong about this, though.

Comment: Im unable to use the result ID[NSString] with the function. It crashes.

Comment: what does it exactly say in the debugger when it crashes?

Comment: the function startForPostWithGraphPath:(NSString*) graphObject:(id<FBGraphObject>)
it keep crashing if i were to use the resultID in NSString format.

Comment: did you try removing the fbsdk:create_object key? how many other keys do you have in your dictionary just before posting? do any keys have the value '1', if yes, try removing that key just before posting.

Comment: the object have 3 values, ["fbsdk:create_object", null], ["id", "440774662705462"], ["data", (NSDictionary)[EMPTY]].

Comment: when i remove the key(fbsdk:create_object). it does not crash. But it gives an error at the end of the function call. 
Error sharing story: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk error 5.)

Comment: can you, using the graph api explorer at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, replicate the issue with the exact same objects? try posting the same object from that page, do you still get the same error?

Comment: in the graph explorer, i type [me/objects/sotd_facebook:new_zombie].
and it gave me a bunch of items that i think i tried before.
the object id [440774662705462] is one of the item in that array.
Within the item, it has a post object link, when i clicked it.
It refers to another post item.

Comment: is there a subscribe action type defined for your object type? if true, try removing it.

Comment: no, there is not subscribe action type. the object Inherits From Object. While the action type is default with a new property for the zombie object. Both the object and the action is used by the stories to create a story unique to the user.

Comment: well, I really don't know why then.. i know it's obvious but just to be sure, are you on the latest SDK?

Comment: yup. i am. im also confused what should i see.

Comment: it should give you the object id... but i really don't have any other idea why this could be happening at all. (sorry for the late comment, skipped it without realizing it)

Comment: It is by using method described in this answer which makes it useles. My next shot is going throught Facebook official samples, since those #$%^&&$ can't post a working code on their docs

Answer (score 0):

I just added these lines before API call and that works fine!

```
    object[@"create_object"] = @"1";
    object[@"fbsdk:create_object"] = @"1";
```

It seems this is a bug in Facebook SDK! it tries to encode Boolean value

Sample code should be something like this

```
    NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *object =
        [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"{YOUR NAMESPACE}:{YOUR OBJECT TYPE}"
                                                title:@"title"
                                                image:@"https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png"
                                                  url:@"http://samples.ogp.me/192059197639963"
                                          description:@"description"];

    object[@"create_object"] = @"1";
    object[@"fbsdk:create_object"] = @"1";

    [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/objects/{YOUR NAMESPACE}:{YOUR OBJECT TYPE}"
                                       graphObject:object
                                 completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                     id result,
                                                     NSError *error) {
                                     NSLog(@"%@",result);
                                 }];
}
```