# How to suppress Facebook default creation action (post) on creating Open Graph object

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am creating a photo app for iOS. I have a custom action-type pair, "take a photo" defined in my app. I first create the "photo" object (I have a user-generated image, and I'm first uploading the photo and getting the staging URI. this code is after that):

```
NSMutableDictionary *imageData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:
                                          @{
                                          @"url" : stagingURL,
                                          @"user_generated" : @"true",

                                          }];
NSMutableDictionary<FBOpenGraphObject> *object =
        [FBGraphObject openGraphObjectForPostWithType:@"tonerapp:photo"
                                                title:@"photo"
                                                image:imageData
                                                  url:@"http://tonerapp.info"
                                          description:title];
//post the object to facebook
[FBRequestConnection startForPostOpenGraphObject:object completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
            if(result != nil){
                NSString* resultID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
                NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject> *actionDict = [FBGraphObject graphObject];
                actionDict[@"photo"] = resultID;
                [self postTakeActionToFacebookWithOpenGraphObject:actionDict completion:action];

            }else{
                action(NO);
            }
        }];
```

After posting the object, I publish the "take" action in the completion handler as seen above. Here is the code for posting the "take" action with the "photo" object:

```
-(void)postTakeActionToFacebookWithOpenGraphObject:(NSMutableDictionary<FBGraphObject>*)ogObject completion:(booleanAction)action{
  if(self.selectedPlace != nil){
      ogObject[@"place"] = [self.selectedPlace id];
  }
  if(self.taggedFriends != nil && self.taggedFriends.count > 0){
      ogObject[@"tags"] = self.taggedFriends;
  }
  [FBRequestConnection startForPostWithGraphPath:@"me/tonerapp:take"
                                   graphObject:ogObject
                             completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                 id result,
                                                 NSError *error) {
                                 if(result != nil){
                                     NSLog(@"oldu");
                                     action(YES);
                                 }else{
                                     action(NO);
                                 }

                             }];
}
```

Here is the result:

[image: posted two actions]

First a "post" action is created, then the "take" action is applied to the photo. I need to get rid of the "post" action. More weirdly, My Open Graph dashboard looks like this:

[image: default actions added automatically]

I delete the "Object" type and the "Post" action, but every other time, they are added to my actions again. I am suspecting that something that I'm doing wrong would be the cause of both "default post creation action" problem and the default pairs being added to my dashboard. I go to my App's settings and change the subscribe (creation) action of my photo type:

[image: creation action setting]

Then I try posting my photo again. Even though my creation action is "take", a "post" action is created:

[image: post action]

But I'm not able to create any "take" action this time. It fails with this response:

```
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 1611231;
        message = "A post action for this object already exists.";
        type = Exception;
    };
};
code = 500;
```

Shouldn't this be just the opposite? Shouldn't I be messing it up if I *don't* set my default creation action to my custom action? I've also tried creating the photo object "on-the-fly" (without "post"ing it first and sending the object JSON data directly in the "take" action, which appears to be the natural way of doing it), but it also fails just as in this example: [Example Facebook object code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17563582/example-facebook-object-code). Am I missing something, or is there something seriously wrong with the Open Graph API?

Thanks,

Can.

**UPDATE:** I have July 2013 migrations enabled.

Comment: i'm shocked that this question doesn't have more vote ups.. seriously

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you create an (user-owned) open graph object through the Object API (which is what you're using with startForPostOpenGraphObject, and also through the share dialog), then there will be a "Post" action that's created. The only way around it is to host your own open graph objects.

Think of it this way, what you're really doing is actually 2 separate operations.

1. You create an open graph object (i.e. you "posted" an object)
2. You create an open graph action (i.e. your "take" action) which acts on the object

Each of them will result in a separate activity in the activity log. This separation is important because you can reuse the same object in a different action, and it has to show up in the user's activity log because it's a user owned object.

See also https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/

Comment: I know that they are two different actions (creating, and taking). I'm okay with seeing it twice in the activity log, but I don't want "story pollution" created by my app, so I don't want people seeing double stories in the news ticker/news feed.

And I still don't understand why subscribe action doesn't work properly.

Comment: In your case, there's actually now 3 different types of actions - post, subscribe, and take. The old "creation" action is now the "subscribe" action, and is different from the "post" action. Any user-generated object will have a "post" action associated with it. You can also set a "subscribe" action in order for the user to get notifications on "likes". "Post" actions do not show up in news feed. See also - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-object-types/#creation

Comment: actually subscribe action needs to be the 'take' action (and the example at link exactly gives the example of 'taking a photo') but when I set the subscribe action to 'take' i'm getting 'A post action for this object already exists.' error even though i've set 'unique action' to 'multiple'. if i remove the 'take' action as the subscribe action, i can post it. are you sure that post actions do not show up in the news feed?

Comment: Hmm, what you're seeing with regards to the subscribe action definitely seems like a bug, please file one here - https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: i'll be filing a bug report to Facebook then. i think it has to do with the object being a open graph created object using the graph api (as opposed to being an object fetched from meta tags in a URL), as the object is first "posted", the system counts that one as the action, and my explicit "take" action is seen as a duplicate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34020/discussion-between-ming-li-and-can-poyrazoglu)

Comment: @MingLi: I have a follow up question, I was facing same issue and I was referring to facebook docs https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-object-api/ which says you can publish story using object created using object API and youtube video given at the bottom of this page also shows the same thing for android, it creates an action(publish story) using the object id that it just created using API, then why is it giving error to me saying that the Post action already exists?

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the question is here. Please create a new question with some code samples. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

@can Poyrazoglu

You should you this methods if you don't to create story for each post. If the there are multiple images from the same post, it will group the image and make the album on the whole only instead of creating the separate post.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[params setObject:@"your custom message" forKey:@"message"];
[params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image) forKey:@"picture"];
_shareToFbBtn.enabled = NO; //for not allowing multiple hits

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error) 
 {
 if (error) 
 {
     //showing an alert for failure
     [self alertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Unable to share the photo please try later."];
 } 
 else
 {
     //showing an alert for success
     [UIUtils alertWithTitle:@"Facebook" message:@"Shared the photo successfully"];
 }
 _shareToFbBtn.enabled = YES;
 }];
```

Comment: have you ever read my question? what does this have to do with open graph objects?